# How to access to a method of an object that is in a list

Tags: java, list, object

Hi I have a list of objects,

```
 myclass obj1 = new myclass();
 myclass obj2 = new myclass();
 obj1.name("hello");
 obj2.name("bye");
 List objectsList = new ArrayList
 objectsList.add(obj1);
 objectsList.add(obj2);
```

how can I access to methods of each object in the list?
   I have tried the following but I dont have access to methods.

```
Object obj = objectsList.get(1);
obj. <<< no access to methods
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast them to myclass.

```
((myclass) obj).methodOfMyClass();
```

Comment: You *could* do that - but it's much cleaner to use a generic collection in the first place.

Answer (score 9):

The code you've given won't even compile... but if you use generics then you'll end up with strongly-typed elements when you fetch:

```
// TODO: Use a better class name which obeys Java naming conventions
// Ditto name => setName
List<myclass> list = new ArrayList<myclass>();
list.add(obj1);
list.add(obj2);

...
myclass obj = list.get(1);
System.out.println(obj1.getName());
```

Comment: I did the same the point was that I had to change Object to myclass thanks.

Comment: @EmeEmertana: You had to do more than that - you had to use generics, or add a cast. Without that, `myclass obj = list.get(1);` wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

One way, given how you've coded it, is to cast the objects as `myclass`, since the `Object` class does not define such methods.